# How can I display commit's position in the history relative to tags (and branches)?

Tags: git, bash

I'm looking for a way to get information about where a commit occurred relative to tags (and branches if possible). Is there some kind of command or group of commands (if necessary, I can use any [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) commands as well) that I could give a commit hash and receive a list of all tags (and branches) in order with the commit in the correct position relative to the other tags? For example, if `<commit-hash>` occurred between `tag2` and `tag3`, then the following command:

```
[command(s)] <commit-hash>
```

Would result in something like the following output:

```
branch1
tag1
tag2
<commit-hash>
tag3
branch2
master
```

I tried using `git log` to do this, but I'm really not sure where to start. Would this even be possible?

Comment: For tags `git describe` and `git describe --contains` should work.

Comment: Do you mean when `tag2` and `tag3` were created? Tag and branch heads are moving targets.

Comment: Annotated tags don't move (generally). Lightweight ones do as do branch refs. They also don't carry "creation" information so you can't really get that from them.

Comment: Tag names _may_ be moved, but at any moment in time they refer to fixed absolute commits which do indeed have a relative position and often it's useful to know that.

Answer (score 4):

`git describe --tags $rev` will give you a short description (see the man page for details) of the tag immediately before the revision.

`git describe --contains $rev` will give you the first tag that contains the revision.

`git rev-list --branches --tags $rev` might be a useful place to start also. You might be able to get something like what you want by using some of the "History Simplification" arguments to that function. I'd try `--simplify-by-decoration` first and then possibly `--dense`.

To control the output of `git rev-list` you can use the `--format` argument. Use `--format=%d` to get the ref names (in an unfortunately annoying format however).

Comment: `git describe --contains $rev` was helpful, but for some reason `git describe --tags $rev` returns `fatal: No tags can describe $rev.
Try --always, or create some tags.`. I can't see any reason that this would happen since there should be many tags which occur before my commit. Maybe I'm misunderstanding something though.

`git rev-list` is also interesting, but do you know if I can get it to display tag names and branch names instead of commit hashes?

Comment: @stiemannkj1 That error should mean that git couldn't find a commit with a tag that was reachable from that commit. Are you sure there are such tags? Can you find one manually with `git log --decorate --simplify-by-decoration $revid`? (Or without `--simplify-by-decoration`?)

Comment: hmmm that doesn't return anything, so maybe I'm mistaken about the tags.